# Array declared only on root process

Tags: arrays, fortran, mpi

In MPI in Fortran specifically, is it possible and a good choice to have an array defined only on the root process? For example something like this:

```
program test
implicit none

include 'mpif.h'

all mpi_init(ierr)

call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world,myid,ierr)
call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world,numproc,ierr) 

if (myid .eq. 0) then
    complex(8), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: array
end if

   ...

if (myid .eq. 0) then
    allocate(array(2,2))
end if

   ...

end program
```

As you can guess, I already tried this and it does not work, as in Fortran declarations need to be on top. But I was hoping for a way around this?

This way, the array would also not eat into my "virtual" memory right? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you pointed out, you cannot have declaration statements in `IF`-blocks or anywhere after the declaration block of the procedure. However, declaring the array as `ALLOCATABLE` on all processes, and allocating only on some is allowed, and in my opinion a good choice.

```
! Declare as allocatable on all processes
complex(8), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: array

   ...

! Allocate only on some
if (myid .eq. 0) then
    allocate(array(2,2))
end if
```

This way, the program will not consume any additional memory on other processes.

Comment: there is no tricks? because what you suggested, i already do -- but find myself with a very large virtual memory consumption (in linux i top and my "virt" is much higher than expected"

Comment: Are you convinced something else is not eating your memory? I frequently do this kind of declaration and allocation on select processes without problems.

Comment: I believe not, because all arrays i have are allocatable and the "virt" value is high even at the start of the run, before i allocate any of the arrays (at that same time the "res" value is practically zero). Well, if there are no tricks, i guess i'll have to find a different way around it.

Comment: @liskawc I wonder if your code is holding onto some space in case you allocate the array. Perhaps you could `allocate` it to some small value on the slave processes and then immediately `deallocate` it?

Comment: @KyleKanos do i understand correctly: allocate(array(2,2)), array=dcmplx(0.0d0,0.0d0), deallocate(array)?

Comment: @liskawc: I do not think even giving it a value would be necessary, but that is the idea I was thinking.

Comment: @KyleKanos i tried it, but it didnt help -- i did get it working tho, although i had to remove some arrays
 ---- thanks for your help and ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the (full) array on each process? If not, try to allocate it in chunks: Proc0: 1--10, Proc1: 11--20, etc. Then, each process only needs to allocate its chunk. You might need a way of mapping between global indices (1--20 in this example) and local indices (1--10 for each process).

Of course, you need to collect all chunks from all processes to the root process at some point (e.g. I/O), but you might be able to do this sequentially without any further memory.

Comment: I distribute other arrays (and they work as expected), but the array mentioned in the question would only be declared on master.